How to put multiple values in dao query running with gutter action for database inspector
I need to put a list of values for my dao query running with help of gutter action in Android Studio Database Inspector. When i put only one value all works fine. But i cant figure out how to put multiple values.
IDE screenshot
I tryed 1, 2, 3; 1 2 3; (1, 2, 3); {1, 2, 3} etc... Nothing works. My query works in app with given list and works when values are inlined into the query.
Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 Patch 1

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
